# mongo query regex inside a list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a collection that contains a list field. The list field contains URLs. I want to search that field and pull out all documents where that pattern appears in at least one element in the list. This is one of my first attempts.

```
query = collection.find({
'third_party_urls' : {'$in' : ['/.woff/']}
})
```

This returns zero documents, but I know the condition is true in many cases. [MongoDB's documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) states that I can't use the $regex operator in a list, but I can use js object regex. According to MongoDB and a quick google search about js regex, I write a pattern encapsulated in / /. So I am confident that I'm using js regex correctly, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: MongoDB implicitly performs array element matches, you do not need $in for that and $in in MQL has different meaning from SQL IN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have a collection named `so`. We insert several documents using following commands in mongo shell:

```
db.so.insert({urls: ["apple", "banana"]})
db.so.insert({urls: ["apple2", "banana2"]})
db.so.insert({urls: ["apple3", "banana3", "cherry"]})
db.so.insert({urls: ["mongo"]})
```

Then we can find all documents that has at least one element that begins with `apple` by issuing:

```
db.so.find({urls: /^apple.*/})
```

OR

```
db.so.find({urls: {$regex: "^apple.*"}})
```

The result is something like below:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef6829b25a20c5a694d8522"), "urls" : [ "apple", "banana" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef682a525a20c5a694d8523"), "urls" : [ "apple2", "banana2" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef682d425a20c5a694d8524"), "urls" : [ "apple3", "banana3", "cherry" ] }
```

Comment: The $regex answer worked, the other didn't. Interesting, because Mongo says you can't use the $regex operator inside a list.